# Tiny gap between ornaments with pgfornamentline

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfornament

I want to have have two ornaments right next to each other that stretch across the text width. I can do this with the `pgfornaments` package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0, 0) {};
\node (B) at (\textwidth, 0) {};
\pgfornamentline{A}{B}{2}{88}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there is a tiny gap between the two ornaments. The following image is zoomed in at the point where the two ornaments meet.

[image]

Is there a way to make sure there is no gap in between the ornaments? If not, will this be noticeable when printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little more complex code, so that the ornaments overlap a bit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, 0) {};
    \node (B) at (\textwidth, 0) {};
    \node (A') at (\textwidth/2-5pt, 0) {};
    \node (B') at (\textwidth/2+5pt, 0) {};

    \path (A) to[ornament=88] (B');
    \path (A') to[ornament=88] (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]